# Return a Selected an Option out of a List

Tags: python, list, if-statement, return

I am having trouble returning an option of a list.

For example:

```
 Fruits = {
     'Apple': Apple, 'Banana': Banana, 'Orange': Orange}

 def Choose_Fruit():
   Choice = input('Choose a fruit: ')
   if Choice not in Fruits:
     Choose_Fruit()
   return Choice
```

If I type 'Appppple', it will force me to choose again. If I then type 'Apple', it successfully returns the Choice but if I were to print it would return 'Appppple' instead of 'Apple'. It prints the first input rather than the one that satisfies the if statement.

Comment: It will always return the value from the first attempt, you do not catch the return value from the recursive calls. To fix, return from your recursive call to `Choose_Fruit` e.g. `return Choose_Fruit()`. Besides which there are better ways to achieve what you want see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: You're throwing away the result of `Choose_Fruit()`

Answer (score 2):

The very simplest fix is to return from your recursive call to `Choose_Fruit`.

```
# there isnt much point this being a dict.
Fruits = {'Apple': 'Apple', 'Banana': 'Banana', 'Orange': 'Orange'}

def Choose_Fruit():
    Choice = input('Choose a fruit: ')
    if Choice not in Fruits:
        return Choose_Fruit()
    return Choice

print(Choose_Fruit())
```

At present the return value from any recursive calls are thrown away and the value input in the first iteration is stored and returned in all cases.